# AWS SQS Stream Not Shutting Down

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, akka-stream

On empty receive from AWS SQS I am trying to shutdown and stop listening using below code but it is not happening-

```
val queueSourceSettings: SqsSourceSettings = SqsSourceSettings(
    getQueue(queueType).waitTimeSeconds,
    getQueue(queueType).maxBufferSize,
    getQueue(queueType).maxBatchSize,
    messageAttributeNames = Seq(
      MessageAttributeName(TRANSACTION_ID.name)
    ),
      closeOnEmptyReceive = true
  )
SqsSource(endpoint.queue.url, endpoint.client, endpoint.queueSourceSettings)
      .via(flow)
      .recoverWithRetries(-1, {
        case e =>
          logger.error("Stream Faiure: ", e)
          streamFailure(e)
          SqsSource(endpoint.queue.url, endpoint.client, endpoint.queueSourceSettings)
            .via(flow)
      })
      .runWith(SqsAckSink(endpoint.queue.url)(ec, endpoint.client))
```

Comment: what exactly is the error?

Comment: @RohithJoseph no error, it keeps on listening to the SQS unless the process is terminated.